# Reporting Services custom assembly: accessing report parameters

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm writting a custom assembly to be referenced in a report. I'd like to be able to access the `Report` object from that assembly, so that I could then access the report parameters and other stuff that I can access in custom RDL code by using `Report.stuff`.

I obviously need to reference some reporting services assembly to do this, yet I can't figure out which. I tried `Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore`, since it has a class `Report` with various properties like `Parameters` etc., but when I tried to pass the `Report` object from the RDL custom code section to my class, I got this error:

> `Unable to cast object of type 'ReportExprHostImpl' to type 'Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportRendering.Report'.`

There's also an assembly which exposes various interfaces and an abstract class `Report`, but it doesn't seem to have the parameters as a property.

So the question is, how could I achieve this, what assembly do I have to reference ? And if possible, can I access the `Report` object without passing it from the RDL, i.e. so that I could just register an instance of my class and later write expressions like:

> `=Utils.DoStuffWhileReferencingReportParameters(Fields!field.Value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference these two dlls in your library:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore
Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingObjectModel

Put the following code in your library (as an example)

```
using Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportObjectModel;

public static string Test(Parameters item)
{

    return item ["my_parameter_name"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Here’s an example expression to use in your RDL file:

```
=MyNameSpace.MyStaticClass.Test(Parameters)
```

Comment: I don't think referencing ProcessingCore is necessary and I've found out that referencing the object model does not solve the exact problem I had, in fact I found out it's basically impossible to reference the parameters in the dll without passing them from the RDL somehow - that's what I ended up doing, I made the constructor accept the Parameters collection. Anyways, for your effort - I accept your answer :)